# Importing a list from SharePoint to Excel as a Range (or with a fixed Table name)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

so I have the code below that pulls a list from SharePoint and imports it to Excel. My problem is, it imports it as a Table not as a Range and I cannot automatically convert it to range as the Table name is different every time I run the script (Table1, Table2, ... and so on).

My question is the following: Can I import the list from SharePoint as an Excel Range straight away, so that I don't have to convert it? If not, can I make it so every time I run the import procedure the name of the imported Table is fix?

Here's my code:

```
   Sub SharePoint_Import()
        Dim objMyList As ListObject
        Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
        Dim strSPServer As String
        Const SERVER As String = "xxxx.xxxxx.xxx.net/xxxx/xxxx" 'SP server
        Const LISTNAME As String = "{1234567-1234-1234-1234-1234567891}" 'SP List ID
        Const VIEWNAME As String = "" 

            Set RData = Sheets("rawdata") 'reset import sheet
            RData.UsedRange.ClearContents

        strSPServer = "https://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin" '<- _vti_bin is necessary
        Set objWksheet = RData

          Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1"))
          Set objMyList = Nothing
          Set objWksheet = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

[1] Change `RData.UsedRange.ClearContents` to `RData.Cells.Clear`. This will clear the sheet completely. Removes formats, text, tables etc..

[2] Once the table is imported, add this code. Since there is going to be only one table, you can use the table number to work with it.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = RData.ListObjects(1)

Dim tblRng As Range
Set tblRng = tbl.Range

'~~> Convert table to range
tbl.Unlist

'~~> Comment this in case you do not
'~~> want to remove the formatting
With tblRng
    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    .Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
End With
```

Comment: Yep this solution works perfectly even with dynamic Table names. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can query a Sharepoint list using ADODB. Check the following code (untested because I don't have Sharepoint available, but have used something similar in the past)

```
Const SERVER As String = "xxxx.xxxxx.xxx.net/xxxx/xxxx" 'SP server
Const LISTNAME As String = "{1234567-1234-1234-1234-1234567891}" 'SP List ID

Dim connStr As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" _
        & "DATABASE=" & SERVER _
        & ";LIST=" & LISTNAME & ";"
conn.Open connStr
Set rs = conn.Execute("select * from list")

Dim rData As Worksheet
Set rData = thisworknbook.Sheets("rawdata") 'reset import sheet
rData.UsedRange.ClearContents
rData.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
conn.Close
```